# pandas dataframe and external list interaction

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which looks like this

```
   betasub0  betasub1  betasub2  betasub3  betasub4  betasub5  betasub6  betasub7  betasub8  betasub9  betasub10
0  0.009396  0.056667  0.104636  0.067066  0.009678  0.019402  0.029316  0.187884  0.202597  0.230275   0.083083
1  0.009829  0.058956  0.108205  0.068956  0.009888  0.019737  0.029628  0.187611  0.197627  0.225660   0.083903
2  0.009801  0.058849  0.108092  0.068927  0.009886  0.019756  0.029690  0.188627  0.200235  0.224703   0.081434
3  0.009938  0.059595  0.109310  0.069609  0.009970  0.019896  0.029854  0.189187  0.199424  0.221968   0.081249
4  0.009899  0.059373  0.108936  0.069395  0.009943  0.019852  0.029801  0.188979  0.199893  0.222922   0.081009
```

Then I have a vector `dk` that looks like this:

```
[0.18,0.35,0.71,1.41,2.83,5.66,11.31,22.63,45.25,90.51,181.02]
```

What I need to do is:

1. calculate a new vector which is

```
psik = [np.log2(dki/1e3) for dki in dk]
```

2. calculate the sum of each row multiplied with the `psik` vector (just as the SUMPRODUCT function of excel)
3. calculate the log2 of each `psik` value

expected output should be:

```
   betasub0  betasub1  betasub2  betasub3  betasub4  betasub5  betasub6  betasub7  betasub8  betasub9  betasub10  psig         dg
0  0.009396  0.056667  0.104636  0.067066  0.009678  0.019402  0.029316  0.187884  0.202597  0.230275  0.083083  -5.848002631  0.017361042
1  0.009829  0.058956  0.108205  0.068956  0.009888  0.019737  0.029628  0.187611  0.197627  0.22566   0.083903  -5.903532822  0.016705502
2  0.009801  0.058849  0.108092  0.068927  0.009886  0.019756  0.02969   0.188627  0.200235  0.224703  0.081434  -5.908820802  0.016644383
3  0.009938  0.059595  0.10931   0.069609  0.00997   0.019896  0.029854  0.189187  0.199424  0.221968  0.081249  -5.930608559  0.016394906
4  0.009899  0.059373  0.108936  0.069395  0.009943  0.019852  0.029801  0.188979  0.199893  0.222922  0.081009  -5.924408689  0.016465513
```

I would do that with a for loop cycling over the rows like this

```py
for r in rows:
    psig_i = sum([d[i]*ri for i,ri in enumerate(r)])
    psig.append(sum([d[i]*ri for i,ri in enumerate(r)]))
    dg.append(np.log2(psig_i))

df['psig'] = psig
df['dg'] = dg
```

Is there any other way to update the `df` without iterating through its rows?

**EDIT:** I found the solution and I am ashamed for how simple it is

```
df['psig']=df.mul(psik).sum(axis=1)
df['dg'] = df[psig].apply(lambda x: np.log2(x))
```

**EDIT2:** now, my `df` has more entries, so I have to `filter` it with a regex to find only the columns with a name starting with "basesub".

I have my array `psik` and a new column ``psig`in the`df`. I would like to calculate for each row (i.e. each value of` psig```):

```
sum(((psik-psig)**2)*betasub[0...n])
```

I did it like this, but maybe there's a better way?

```py
PsimPsig2     = [[(psik_i-psig_i)**2 for psik_i in psik] for psig_i in list(df['psig'])]
psikmpsigname = ['psikmpsig'+str(i) for i in range(len(psik))]
dfPsimPsig2   = pd.DataFrame(data=PsimPsig2,columns=psikmpsigname)
siggAL        = np.power(2,(np.power(pd.DataFrame(df.filter(regex=r'^betasub[0-9]',axis=1).values*dfPsimPsig2.values).sum(axis=1),0.5)))
df['siggAL']  = siggAL
```

Comment: can you also provide the expected output?

Comment: You are right, I'll update my question providing an expected result and the "for-loop" solution.

Comment: `df['dg'] = df[psig].apply(lambda x: np.log2(x))` should be `df['dg']=np.log2(df.psig)`